# Icon stack on each other when I toggle Class

Tags: jquery, css

I want change the icon from 'search' to 'X' while using `toggleClass`. I tried using `opacity` and `z-index`, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').click(function() { 
        $('.search-hide').fadeToggle();
        $('#search').toggleClass('activex');
    }); 
})
```

```css
#search {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.activex {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background:url('x.png');
    z-index: 1001;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please please include your markup too. We can’t guess from incomplete information.

Comment: In css, element id takes priority over class. So #search will overrule .activex. So z-index and opacity don’t help. You need to use class names only. It’s always a preferred practice.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you have set an image inside your #search element in which case the html will display said image and set the background of #search to 'x.png' at the same time.

Comment: So i should create another div with an <img> inside and use that div's class for toggling. Is it right ?

Comment: @limboo Maybe try doing them the same way and just add a background image to #search instead of a child <img>.
Or you could just use jquery to change the source of the child <img>

Comment: Can I ask you for the Jquery code used to change  <img> inside the class

Comment: I don’t know how your html looks so add an id tag to your img example id=“searchimg” and then for jquery $(‘#searchimg’).attr(‘src’, ‘x.png’); I’m using my phone so the quotes are weird you’ll need to replace those.

Comment: it worked, thank you . Now I have to figure out the way to implement toggle in it so it can switch back to the previous image.